# How do I eliminate this n+1 query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Models:

```rb
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :device_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :device_locations do
    def previous
      order('device_locations.removed_at DESC').first
    end
  end
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :device_locations
  has_many :devices, through: :device_locations
end

class DeviceLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Controller Action:

```rb
# LocationsController

def show
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  @device_locations = @location.device_locations.includes(:device).where(removed_at: nil)
end
```

View:

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Install Date</th><th>Uninstall Date</th><th>Previous Location</th></tr>
  <%- @device_locations.each do |device_location| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to device_location.device.name, device_location.device %></td>
      <td><%= device_location.installed_at %></td>
      <td><%= device_location.removed_at %></td>
      <td><%= link_to device_location.device.locations.previous.name, device_location.device.locations.previous %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The difficulty here is avoiding the n+1 query generated by `device_location.device.locations.previous.name`. It's like I need to join the table to itself?

Without this column removed from the view the log reads:

```
Started GET "/locations/1" for ::1 at 2019-08-24 11:09:55 -0400
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by LocationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Location Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:69:in `set_location'
  Rendering locations/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  DeviceLocation Load (14.6ms)  SELECT "device_locations".* FROM "device_locations" WHERE "device_locations"."location_id" = ? AND "device_locations"."removed_at" IS NULL  [["location_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/locations/show.html.erb:9
  Device Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 5], ["id", 28], ["id", 35], ["id", 51], ["id", 57], ["id", 61], ["id", 86], ["id", 94], ["id", 99], ["id", 107], ["id", 115], ["id", 125], ["id", 139], ["id", 148], ["id", 151], ["id", 159], ["id", 164], ["id", 165], ["id", 168], ["id", 177]]
  ↳ app/views/locations/show.html.erb:9
  Rendered locations/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 20.7ms | Allocations: 4172)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 7.3ms | ActiveRecord: 15.9ms | Allocations: 6079)
```

With the column present it reads:

```
Started GET "/locations/1" for ::1 at 2019-08-24 11:10:51 -0400
Processing by LocationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Location Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:69:in `set_location'
  Rendering locations/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  DeviceLocation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "device_locations".* FROM "device_locations" WHERE "device_locations"."location_id" = ? AND "device_locations"."removed_at" IS NULL  [["location_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/locations/show.html.erb:9
  Device Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "devices".* FROM "devices" WHERE "devices"."id" IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 5], ["id", 28], ["id", 35], ["id", 51], ["id", 57], ["id", 61], ["id", 86], ["id", 94], ["id", 99], ["id", 107], ["id", 115], ["id", 125], ["id", 139], ["id", 148], ["id", 151], ["id", 159], ["id", 164], ["id", 165], ["id", 168], ["id", 177]]
  ↳ app/views/locations/show.html.erb:9
  Location Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "device_locations" ON "locations"."id" = "device_locations"."location_id" WHERE "device_locations"."device_id" = ? ORDER BY device_locations.removed_at DESC LIMIT ?  [["device_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/device.rb:5:in `previous'
  CACHE Location Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "device_locations" ON "locations"."id" = "device_locations"."location_id" WHERE "device_locations"."device_id" = ? ORDER BY device_locations.removed_at DESC LIMIT ?  [["device_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/device.rb:5:in `previous'

  ... N times

  CACHE Location Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "device_locations" ON "locations"."id" = "device_locations"."location_id" WHERE "device_locations"."device_id" = ? ORDER BY device_locations.removed_at DESC LIMIT ?  [["device_id", 177], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/device.rb:5:in `previous'
  Rendered locations/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 50.7ms | Allocations: 40363)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 47.7ms | ActiveRecord: 5.3ms | Allocations: 42252)
```

Comment: Maybe you could use some PostgreSQL magic, see `LAG`/`LEAD` window functions http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/. But you would have to do a lot of SQL manually like joins and selects.

Answer (score -1):

Shauno, have you tried the Bullet gem? it helps you get rid of n+1 queries throughout your application by showing a notice at the bottom of pages when a n+1 query is detected, and it also suggests possible solutions.

https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Just make sure to only add it to your development group in the gemfile.